# (Complex Stieltjes Integral) If $f$ is integrable wrt $\alpha$, is $\overline{f}$ also integrable wrt $\alpha$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

Let $f,\alpha$ be two bounded complex functions on $[0,1]$. We say that $f$ is integrable w.r.t. $\alpha$ iff the Riemann sum $$\sum f(t_i)(\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1}))$$ converges to a fixed number $I\in\mathbb{C}$ as the partition $P=\left\{0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=1\right\}$ gets finer. When this is the case, we write $f\in\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ and that $\int f\,d\alpha=I$. It is known that when $\alpha$ is of bounded variation, $\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ contains all continuous functions.

I have two questions related to this.

> **Q1.** If $f\in\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$, do we have $\overline{f}\in\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ too?

> **Q2.** Does the answer change if we further assume that $\alpha$ is of bounded variation?

There is an example of a pair of sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ such that $\sum a_n b_n$ converges while $\sum \overline{a_n} b_n$ diverges. From this I get a feeling that the answers to my questions are both negative, but I could not find counterexamples by myself.

Comment: The example $\sum a_nb_n$ converges but $\sum \overline{a_n}b_n$ diverges can be found only when $b_n$ is not real. If $b_n$ is real then $\overline{a_n}b_n = \overline{a_n}\overline{b_n} = \overline{a_nb_n}$ so their convergence is equivalent.

Comment: @Riemann I'm sorry but we are dealing with complex valued integrator $\alpha$ here.

Comment: Okay. Then do you mean $t_i = \alpha(x^\ast_i)$, where $x_{i-1}\le x^\ast_i\le x_{i}$?

Comment: @Riemann No, $x_{i-1}\leq t_i\leq x_i$.

Comment: You should really specify in the question that $\alpha$ is not assumed to be real-valued. In any case, good question. I bet the answer is negative as you expect.

Comment: I think the answer to Q2 is positive, while for Q1 it is negative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ such that $\sum a_nb_n$ converges and $\sum \overline{a_n}b_n$ diverges, you can find bounded functions $f$ and $\alpha$ such that $\int f\alpha'$ converges but $\int \overline{f}\alpha'$ diverges. The idea is to choose $f$ and $\alpha$ of opposite argument.

For example, if
$$
f : x \mapsto e^{i/x}, \qquad \alpha(x) = \int_0^x \frac{e^{i/t}}{t} \, dt.
$$
$\alpha$ is well defined because,
$$
\int_\varepsilon^1 \frac{e^{i/t}}{t} \, dt = \int_1^{1/\varepsilon} \frac{e^{iu}}{u} \, du = \int_1^{1/\varepsilon} \frac{\cos(u)}{u} \, du + i\int_1^{1/\varepsilon} \frac{\sin(u)}{u} \, du,
$$
which is known to be convergent when $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. Notice that $\alpha(0) = 0$, $\alpha$ is absolutely continuous but has unbounded variation since its derivative is unbounded. Similarly,
$$
\int_\varepsilon^1 f(t)\alpha'(t) \, dt = \int_1^{1/\varepsilon} \frac{\cos(2u)}{u} \, du + i\int_1^{1/\varepsilon} \frac{\sin(2u)}{u} \, du
$$
is also convergent. However,
$$
\int_\varepsilon^1 \overline{f(t)}\alpha'(t) \, dt = \int_\varepsilon^1 \frac{1}{t} \, dt = -\ln(\varepsilon)
$$
diverges.

Howver, I haven't been able to prove that $\int f d\alpha$ is well defined neither that $\int \overline{f} d\alpha$ is not. Here is what the computation gives given a partition of $[0,1]$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^n f(t_i)(\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i - 1})) & = f(t_1)\alpha(x_1) + \sum_{i = 2}^n f(t_i)\int_{x_{i - 1}}^{x_i} \alpha'(t) \, dt\\
& = \sum_{i = 2}^n \int_{x_{i - 1}}^{x_i} f(t)\alpha'(t) \, dt + \sum_{i = 2}^n \int_{x_{i - 1}}^{x_i} (f(t_i) - f(t))\alpha'(t) \, dt + f(t_1)\alpha(x_1)\\
& = \int_{x_1}^1 f(t)\alpha'(t) \, dt + \sum_{i = 2}^n \int_{x_{i - 1}}^{x_i} (f(t_i) - f(t))\alpha'(t) \, dt + f(t_1)\alpha(x_1),
\end{align*}
$$
and the very same computation holds if you replace $f$ by $\overline{f}$. By boundedeness of $f$ and continuity of $\alpha$, $f(t_1)\alpha(x_1) \rightarrow 0$ and $\overline{f(t_1)}\alpha(x_1) \rightarrow 0$ so it remains to prove that,
$$
\sum_{i = 2}^n \int_{x_{i - 1}}^{x_i} (f(t_i) - f(t))\alpha'(t) \, dt \rightarrow 0, \qquad \sum_{i = 2}^n \int_{x_{i - 1}}^{x_i} (\overline{f(t_i)} - \overline{f(t)})\alpha'(t) \, dt \rightarrow 0.
$$
The first assumtion imply the existence of $\int f d\alpha$ with $\int f d\alpha = \int_0^1 f(t)\alpha'(t) \, dt$ and the second one imply the inexistence of $\int \overline{f} d\alpha$. However, I am struggling to prove them because of the divergence of the derivative of $f$ in $0$, which makes $f(t_i) - f(t)$ hard to bound efficiently. I hope it helped you a bit still !

Comment: This is not a valid answer, but I'll end my bounty with this answer since it is the only one.